# ng-expression after some re-assignment it blow out something strange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have my html:

```
<td>
  <form name="forma" id="changeInput" style="display: none">
    <input name="hiddenField">
  </form>
  <div id="descrizioneEventoOriginale" ng-click="modifyDescrizione()">
    {{risultato[0].descrizione}}
  </div>
</td>
```

JS:

```
$scope.modifyDescrizione = function() {
    var forma = $('form[name="forma"]');

    $('#descrizioneEventoOriginale').hide();
    forma.css('display', 'block');
    console.log('descrizione', $('#descrizioneEventoOriginale').get(0));
    forma.focusout(function() {
      if (forma.get(0) == null) {
        //NON E' STATO CAMBIATO NULLA,RIMOSTRO LA DESCRIZIONE
        forma.css('display', 'none');
        forma.val("");
        console.log('descrizione', $('#descrizioneEventoOriginale').get(0));
        $('#descrizioneEventoOriginale').show();
      } else if (forma.get(0) != null) {
        modifica = true;
        $scope.risultato[0].descrizione = forma.get(0);
        forma.css('display', 'none');
        if (selettore == "evento") {
          data_inizio_ev = $scope.risultato[0].data_inizio;
          data_fine_ev = $scope.risultato[0].data_fine;
          data_compilazione_ev = $scope.risultato[0].data_compilazione;
        }
        if (selettore == "condizione") {}
        forma.val("");
        $('#descrizioneEventoOriginale').show();
      }

    });
```

What I'm doing is a Inline edit for my description field:
I have an input that is invisible and a div that shows the description : if you click on description I hide the div and show the input.
After many times that I do this procedure, it print this output :
[image]

**Has anyone an idea why it gives this error?**

Comment: is this printing in the console ?

Comment: yes it is, it prints in the console